# Cannot update during an existing state transition, additionally function passed as boolean and I dont know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-context

I have an App which has a state that contains the information if the user is loggged in or not. This state is passed to a Context Provider:

**App.native.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Orientation, { orientation } from "react-native-orientation";
import Navigator from "./navigation/Navigator";
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const LoginContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});


export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      this.login = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          isLoggedIn: true
        }));
        console.log("Logged in!");
      };

      this.logout = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          isLoggedIn: false
        }));
        console.log("Logged out!");
      };   

      this.state = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        login: this.login,
        logout: this.logout
      };      
  }  

  componentDidMount = () => {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  };

  render() {
    return <LoginContext.Provider value={this.state}><Navigator /></LoginContext.Provider>;
  }
}
```

In (almost) every screen of the App I want to show an Icon in the header, e.g.:

**SearchScreen.js**

```js
import styles from './styles';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import  LoginIcon  from '../../components/LoginIcon'
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'

class SearchScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerTitle: "Suchen",
      headerRight: <LoginIcon navigation={navigation} />   
    }); 

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle = "dark-content" hidden = {false} backgroundColor = "#338A3E" />
        <Text>This is the SearchScreen.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchScreen;
```

The icon should show either a LogIn or Logout image, depending on the state of the App. I try to do that by using the Context Consumer:

**LoginIcon.js**

```js
import styles from "./styles";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import AntIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";
import {LoginContext} from "../../App.native.js";

const LoginIcon = ({navigation}) => {   
               
    return (
      <LoginContext.Consumer>
        {({isLoggedIn, login, logout}) => {
           return (isLoggedIn ? 
                   <Icon
                    name="logout"
                    type='material-community'
                    containerStyle={styles.icon}                  
                    color="white"                    
                    onPress={logout}
                  />  
                  :
                    <Icon
                    name="login"
                    type='material-community'
                    containerStyle={styles.icon}                  
                    color="white"                    
                    onPress={navigation.navigate("Login")}
                  />  );
          }
        }          
      </LoginContext.Consumer>   
    );    
  
}

export default LoginIcon;
```

Now, when I login (via a LoginScreen not shown here), the state changes as expected (isLoggedIn = true), and the Icon in the Heder of the SearchScreen shows the correct "Logout" button. That is great!

**But when I click this button, I get two errors:**

1: ***Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render'). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.***
 This is a riddle for me, I know I have a design flaw here but don't know how to solve it because ...well, basically everything happens inside a render function?

2) ***Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'onPress' of type 'boolean' supplied to 'Icon', expected 'function'.
in Icon (at withTheme.js:24) in Themed.Icon (at LoginIcon.js:22) in LoginIcon (at SearchScreen.js:12)***
As far as I understand passing props to a function component is possible, but this.props should be left out when calling the prop inside the component. But it does not seem to work. How can I make that work?

Comment: its not a bug related but please... change `return ((isLoggedIn == true) ?... ` to `return isLoggedIn ? ...` as your boolean will always evaluate as true or false and thats enough information for statement condition to evaluate.